# Delete a Cloudflare zone

Tags: terraform, cloudflare

I'm currently working on a terraform script which creates a cloudflare zone and make some configurations and if user sets a boolean variable to true I need to delete this cloudflare zone. This cloudflare zone is in the enterprise plan. Can any of you help me to delete this cloudflare zone using my terraform script? I can downgrade the plan to free plan using a api request to cloudflare.

Is there any terraform function which can be used to delete a zone?

Code

```
resource "cloudflare_zone" "cloudflarecreatezone" {
  count = var.delete ? 0 : 1
  jump_start = "true"
  zone = var.zone_name
  type = "partial"
  plan = "enterprise"
}

resource "cloudflare_waf_group" "Cloudflare_Joomla" {
  count = var.delete ? 0 : 1

  group_id = "dc85d7a0s342918s886s32056069dfa94"
  zone_id = cloudflare_zone.cloudflarecreatezone[count.index].id
  mode = "off"
}

resource "null_resource" "dg" {
  count = var.delete ? 1 : 0
  provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "id=curl -s -k -X GET 
 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/?name=${var.zone_name}' -H \"X-Auth-Email: ${var.email}\" -H \"X-Auth-Key: ${var.api_key}\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\"|awk -F ':' '{print $3}'|awk -F '\"' '{print $2}';curl -s -k -X PATCH -d '{\"plan\":{\"id\":\"0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee\"}}' 'api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/'$id -H \"X-Auth-Email: ${var.email}\" -H \"X-Auth-Key: ${var.api_key}\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\"" interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"] 
 }
}

resource "null_resource" "delete_zone" {
  count = var.delete ? 1 : 0
}
```

TIA

I expect my script to be able to delete the cloudflare zone once the delete variable is set to true

Comment: Show us the script and we might be able to help.

Comment: resource "cloudflare_zone" "cloudflarecreatezone" {
  count = var.delete ? 0 : 1
  jump_start = "true"
  zone = var.zone_name
  type = "partial"  
  plan = "enterprise"
}

Comment: resource "null_resource" "dg" {
  count = var.delete ? 1 : 0
  provisioner "local-exec" {

Comment: command = "id=`curl -s -k -X GET 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/?name=${var.zone_name}' -H \"X-Auth-Email: ${var.email}\" -H \"X-Auth-Key: ${var.api_key}\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\"|awk -F ':' '{print $3}'|awk -F '\"' '{print $2}'`;curl -s -k -X PATCH -d '{\"plan\":{\"id\":\"0feeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee\"}}' 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/'$id -H \"X-Auth-Email: ${var.email}\" -H \"X-Auth-Key: ${var.api_key}\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\""
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
  }
}

Comment: resource "null_resource" "delete_zone" {
  count = var.delete ? 1 : 0
}

Comment: @MarkoE Thank you for your comment. I copied the code above

Comment: Based on your code, it should be enough to have the variable set to `true`. What is the issue here?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE
Thank you for your reply. However, I have some waf groups enabled in my code as below:

resource "cloudflare_waf_group" "Cloudflare_Joomla" {
  count = var.delete ? 0 : 1

  group_id = "dc85d7a0s342918s886s32056069dfa94"
  zone_id = cloudflare_zone.cloudflaresiteadd[count.index].id
  mode = "off"
}
So when I'm running the deleting part of the code I get below error:
Error: HTTP status 400: "Cloudflare Joomla" is not supported in your current free plan (1039)

Comment: OK, so this makes no sense: you reference `cloudflare_zone.cloudflaresiteadd[count.index].id` whereas you use `resource "cloudflare_zone" "cloudflarecreatezone"` to create a zone.

Comment: @MarkoE Sorry! My mistake. In my code it was referenced as cloudflare_zone.cloudflarecreatezone[count.index].id

I have updated the code in the initial question as well

Comment: Do you have an enterprise subscription plan or not?

Comment: I have the enterprise plan

Comment: Have you configured the `cloudflare` provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs#example-usage? If so, can you add that to the question as well?